# Subclassing Warning

Tags: python, warnings

I am building an application with "never fail (unless absolutely must)" philosophy. Non-fatal errors will be collected and presented to end user as warnings in a report. Subclassing Warning class seems to be a good idea, but there is one very strange obstacle: I can only issue warnings using the following library method:

```
warnings.warn(message, category=None, stacklevel=1)`
```

So let's say one of the warnings I need to log is about 99 misspellings in a text document, along with line number where each misspelling occurred:

```
class UserCannotSpell(UserWarning):
    def __init__(self, misspelled_document):
        super().__init__()
        self.document = misspelled_document
        self.misspellings = []

    def add(self, misspelling):
        self.misspellings.append(misspelling)
```

...a document has been processed and a `UserCannotSpell()` object is prepared. The only problem: I cannot `raise` it nor can I `warnings.warn()` it. Any suggestions?

Comment: When I use your class, I can indeed use `warnings.warn` on an instance of it.  There is no "content" message to the warning, but that's because you don't define `__str__`.  What happens when you try to use `warnings,warn` on your object?

Comment: @BrenBarn I cannot pass an object to warnings.warn() -- only a string and a warning type. Therein lies the problem

Comment: Please show the actual code you're using with `warnings.warn`.  As [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) you can pass a Warning instance (including an instance of a subclass of Warning).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @BrenBarn for pointing out that message can be an object. This way subclassing of Warning looks rather ugly but at least it is usable:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    warning_obj = UserCannotSpell('Houston, we have a problem')
    warning_obj.custom_data = 33
    warnings.warn(warning_obj)
```

Output:

```
>>> w
[<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x02E011F0>]

>>> w[0].message.custom_data
33
```